# Check if variable contains any part of post value

Tags: php, foreach

I have an html search form, that is submitting the value 'term':

```
 <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="term" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

Then I have a foreach loop, that is checking if the $item contains the search term 'term'

```
     <?php foreach ($data['page'] as $item): ?>

     <?php if (in_array($_POST['term'], $item)): ?> 

          //do something

      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

At the moment, the search is only working if the search term is exactly the same as the item (term == item. How do I change it so that the search will pick up any entries if the search term contains some parts of the item.

example: at the moment, it will only find a result of "Wembley" by typing in "Wembley" - can I change it so that I can only type in "Wemb" for example, and it will bring up the entry "Wembley"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stripos($haystack, $needle)`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Your code would become:

```
if(stripos($item, $_POST['term']) !=== false) {
    // There is a match, do something (echo?)
}
```